# select on change jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code that does not seem to work:

```js
$('.chosen-select').on('change', function() {
    if ('.chosen-select'.value == '1') {
        $("#tips").html("the color that you want to add.");
    } else if ('.chosen-select'.value == '2') {
        $("#tips").html("the text that you want to add.");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tips"></div>
<select class="chosen-select" style="width:290px;" name="option">
    <option value="1">change background colour</option>
    <option value="2">insert text</option>
    <option value="3">insert arrow</option>
</select>
```

My web browser console is not giving me any error. The code is suppose to change the html of the div based on changing the select option value.

Comment: Hi, Try to load the page first and then call the jQuery by using $(document).ready(function() { PLACE YOUR CODE HERE });

Comment: `if ( '.chosen-select'.value` is not doing what you probably think it is doing. The change handler is executing, but the code in it isn't correct. Try `if ( $(this).val() == '1')`, for starters...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `'.chosen-select'.value` won't work as it's neither a valid jQuery expression nor JavaScript. Instead use `$('.chosen-select').val()`, `this.value` or `$(this).val()`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gzfy03jr/)**

Comment: @Ja͢ck - sure, `this.value` or even `$(this).val()`. All three work.

Comment: All three work in this particular instance, but it will yield different results if there are multiple elements with the same class name.

Comment: @Ja͢ck - right, but for this simple example, all three will work. If there are multiple selects with the same class, then only `this.value` or `$(this).val()` should be used.

Answer (score 4):

Use `if($(this).val() == '1') {` not as `if('.chosen-select'.value == '1')`

```js
   $(function() {
  $('.chosen-select').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).val() == '1') {$("#tips").html( "the color that you want to add.");}
    else if($(this).val() == '2') {$("#tips").html( "the text that you want to add.");}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tips"></div>
<select class="chosen-select" style="width:290px;" name="option">
<option value="1">change background colour</option>
<option value="2">insert text</option>
<option value="3">insert arrow</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below expression doesn't yield the results you want:

```
'.chosen-select'.value
```

It attempts to access the `value` property of a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) object, which is `undefined`, because strings don't have such properties.

Within the change event handler function, you can make good use of the fact that `this` references the `<select>` element:

```
var selectedValue = this.value; // get value from select element
```

Alternatively, use jQuery's [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function to get the value:

```
var selectedValue = $(this).val();
```